# How to retrieve data from subcollection Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to develop a mini application for playing music over the Internet. If you display a list of all the songs from the Firestore at once, everything works correctly. But I need to make a structure: Artist - Album - Track

I have created entries of the kind shown in the screenshot.

[image]

How can I get information from subcollections and make a relationship between artist and receive all his albums. Anyone for the albums and songs.
[Image of structure here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2re1y.png)

Upd. I've got a new problem. I can't get a id of all documents in Artists if i use var artistref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('artist').get(); i have an error The argument type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String?' if i trying to call this variable. I've tried to change var for string, Future, and it won't helped.. Can anyone explain me how i can receive id?
All file:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
}

  var docIds = [];

  Future getDocId() async {
    var artistid = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('artist').get();
    var data = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Artists')
        .doc(artistref);
        .collection('Zeit (Single)')
        .get()
        .then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
            docIds.add(document.reference.id);
          }),
        );
        return data;
  }
Future getdata() async {
    QuerySnapshot on =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('songs').get();
    return on.docs;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getDocId(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: docIds.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return InkWell(
                  child: Card(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(docIds[index]),
                      ),
                    ),
                );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )));
  }
}
```

This function is worked, but the only problem is receiving id to show albums of every album in base:

```
Future getDocId() async { 
var data = FirebaseFirestore.instance .collection('artist') .doc('7AnJV22U....') .collection('Album') .get() .then( (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((document) { 
docIds.add(document.reference.id); 
}), 
); 
return data; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get information from subcollections and make a relationship
> between artist and receive all his albums.

Since you know the id of the Document representing a given artist you need to do as follows to get all the documents of the `Album` sub-collection:

```
var artistId = ...  // Get the Artist document ID
db
.collection("artist")
.doc(artistId)
.collection("Album")
.get()
.then(
    (res) => print("Successfully completed"),
    onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
 );
```

The corresponding documentation page is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).

Note that since, in most of the cases, a Collection contains several documents, I would name the collections with the plural form.

Artists Collection => Artist Document => Albums (sub)Collection => Album Document

Comment: Thanks! 
But i don't know how to show this element on screen using ListView? And i can't receive documents from "artist" collection without a field. Can you help me pls?
Code of main.dart:
https://hastebin.com/afuhiqivow.coffeescript
albumpage.dart: https://hastebin.com/obuqisoqul.kotlin

Comment: You should exactly like you do with the `artist` collection:   `Future getdata() async {QuerySnapshot on = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('artist').doc(artistId).collection("Album").get(); return on.docs;}`.

Comment: Can you update your question with your new code and the detailed explanations of the problem.

Comment: Solved the problem, thanks)